# Convert to async/await

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

```
public async Task<JobViewModel> Handle(EditJobCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (command.JobViewModel == null) throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Empty request.");
            var jobViewModel = command.JobViewModel;
            try
            {
                var job = _mapper.Map<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>(jobViewModel);
                job.Id = command.Id;

                OnBeforeAttach(job);
                _context.Set<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>().Attach(job);
                //_context.MarkModified(job);
               await OnBeforeSave(job);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return jobViewModel;
            }

            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
                throw e;
            }

            catch (DbUpdateException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }

        }
private async Task OnBeforeSave(Job job)
        {
            var entry = _context.Entry(job);
          
            entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            entry.Property(j => j.Name).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(j => j.Description).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(j => j.SAPCode).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(j => j.InitiatedOn).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(j => j.EndDate).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(j => j.ProjectId).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(j => j.TimeStamp).IsModified = true;

            if (job.IsNew)
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            else
            {
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                entry.Property(e => e.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                entry.Property(e => e.CreatedOn).IsModified = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to use await for below line
var entry = _context.Entry(job); but using await gives below error DbEntityEntry does not contain definition for getawaiter

Aslo ,please not i want to use await as calling this method onBeforesave () is giving me error of optimistic concurrency.

Comment: abd how do you come to the idea that you may use `await` here? There's absolutely nothing async in your code, or more specifically nothing that could be awaited.

Comment: I have edited the code , could you please check

Comment: and how does your edit change the mentioned question? `DbContext.Entry()` still is nothing that can be awaited.

Comment: so why does that method OnBeforesave is throwing database concurrency exception

Comment: There is no need for an await or async on `_context.Entry(job)`. This line just tells EF to provide a tracking reference for the provided entity if available. It's *not* going to the database or anything that would need to be `async`/awaitable. This approach for updating entities involves a lot of boilerplate code that is easy to mess up, plus it will fail "late" (on SaveChanges) if you update a Job that isn't actually found in the database.

Comment: @StevePy I understood, but i am getting Database concurrency exception when i have that method. If i comment it it will not throw an concurrency error. Not sure why then i am getting .Do you suggest any code changes in the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimistic concurrency errors implies that your code is using something like a RowVersion Timestamp column for cuncurrency checks. These are used to help guard against "last in wins" data overwrites.

Take the scenario where Bob and Jane both running queries and happen to pick the same record to be updated. Bob makes a change to one field and Saves, then Jane makes a change to a second field and Saves. In your model you are taking *all* fields from a serialized copy at the time of their Read with their specific edits, attaching that as an entity, setting the fields to modified, and attempting to save the changes. Without optimistic concurrency, Jane's changes would be saved, while Bob's changes would be lost, overwritten by Jane's stale data, completely silently. With a RowVersion, the original record would have a RowVersion stamp of "AAAAAAA", when Bob saves his changes, his copy of the RowVersion would be "AAAAAA" which is checked by EF against the current database row. They match, so the update goes through and the row version is updated to "BBBBBB". Now when Jane goes to save her changes, her RowVersion value is still "AAAAA". When EF checks that against the DB row now "BBBBBB" Jane's operation fails due to the concurrency issue detected. Jane's data is stale.

Optimistic concurrency is a safeguard to ensure these types of problems don't happen silently. It is up to the developers as to what the system should do in these scenarios. Such as, Log the fact that it happened and allow the overwrite; Attempt to automatically merge the change; Reject the change and give Jane the current data state to review and apply her change again; etc.

This comes down to how you are performing your update. Whether optimistic concurrency or not, it is not a good idea to deserialize data from a client into an entity, attach it to the DbContext and call `SaveChanges`. The good thing is that your code is being pessimistic with the fields that it is marking as IsModified rather than setting the entire EntityState to Modified, but that is ultimately a lot of boilerplate code to write for every update. It also means your UPDATE statements will include every column nominated whether those values changed or not.

A better way to handle the Update, and concurrency:

(Add in appropriate exception handling, I trimmed out to show the relevant bits)

```
public async Task<JobViewModel> Handle(EditJobCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (command.JobViewModel == null) throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Empty request.");

    var job = _mapper.Map<DataAccess.Domain.Lab.Job>(jobViewModel);
    var job = await _context.Jobs.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == command.JobViewModel.Id);
  
    if(job.RowVersion != command.JobViewModel.RowVersion)
    { // Concurrency issue!  Handle here.
    }

    _mapper.Map(command.JobViewModel, job);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The key differences here in approach:

1. Fetch the job asynchronously from the DB. This ensures we are inspecting and updating the current state of the record. This also ensures that our Edit command actually has a valid Job ID. From here we can also validate that the Job is in an editable state (I.e. not Inactive) and can assert that the current user has permissions to edit that Job etc.
2. Check the RowVersion. This might be a different column name, but essentially our concurrency marker which needs to be passed to the View, and returned in our Edit ViewModel. If these values match, the data hasn't changed so we can continue with the edit. If they don't match you can handle that whether to refresh the client view and alert them that data has possibly changed, or allow the overwrite after logging the concurrency issue.
3. Leverage Automapper to copy allowed values across from the ViewModel to the Entity. In your mapping for VM -> Entity you can configure what fields can be copied across then call Mapper.Map(src, destination). Aside from being a single line of code, the benefit of using the Change Tracking on the entity is that the resulting UPDATE statement will only include fields that actually change (and only if anything actually changed).